# What does it mean if a monster is "vulnerable"?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

Pretty frequently I'll be fighting an enemy and alongside all of the damage numbers that come flying up, I'll see the word "Vulnerable" popup above the enemy hitbox briefly.

What does this convey? Is this a term for staggering an enemy with your attacks? Is it a specific condition like poison?

If it matters, I've been playing almost exclusively in the Finesse tree, using Faeblades and Daggers (whatever I find a better one of at the time), with a heavy investment into the passive skill that allows me a chance to poison my targets.

Comment: It's *super effective!*

Comment: Does the manual mention anything about it?

Comment: @JamesJiao I don't know, don't have a physical copy. I should take a look through the online one, if there is one...

Comment: @JamesJiao Took a look through the ingame manual yesterday. No indication of this status.

Comment: Worth a try I guess!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From, what I've managed to find out, that means that they are vulnerable to a specific type of damage (i.e. spiders and boggarts using fire) which increases the damage done. The opposite is "resisted" where they are strong against a specific element, such as spiders when using poison or fire sprites using fire.

Comment: +1 for more information aside from my observations to this point :)

Comment: It looks like this is indeed correct, and the "stagger" that I'm noticing might just be a side-effect of hitting an enemy with something that they're vulnerable to (like fire with spiders/boggarts, as mentioned).